# Choice column : how to set its content with all existing values

Tags: 2010, column, choice-field

I have a column called *project* based on a static list of values. I would like that list to display all already existing values in *project* and allow the user to add a new one if he does not find the one he wants (so the added value should be displayed next time)

Is it possible or do i have to create a new column with another type ?
The lookup column can't list it's own values ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lookup column and show the user how to add new items to the lookup list.

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what i needed. I created my list, the lookup column and without any JS code

Answer (score 0):

I figure you have a few options:

- use JavaScript on the new/edit form to retrieve a list of existing project values and add it to the Project drop down
- create another list where users can add items and the Project column is a lookup for that list. so on the new/edit form where project is you could add add an option to add a new item to the lookup list. would need to use custom JS here too.